# Vehicles dissapear while running simulation on OSM data using flow-project

Tags: traffic-simulation, flow-project

link to the repository I'm using:
https://github.com/flow-project/flow

I have data from osm and tried to simulate traffic, however while simulation after some period of time cars disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not specify edge distributions in the InitialConfiguration class instance; do go over tutorial 7 (osm) in the tutorials folder in flow, especially towards the end. In all cases, some source code would be much appreciated to get a better sense of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Thanks. But is there shorter way? I'm trying to simulate 3 buses and it seems that I have to get all edges manually.
I should pass edge_distribution and then specify routes according to the tutorial

Comment: EDGES_DISTRIBUTION = [
    "215564506#1",
    "215564506#0", 
    "28812895#6",
    "28812895#5",
    "28812895#4", 
    "28812895#3", 
    "28812895#2", 
    "28812895#1",
    "215564506#2",
    "526772298#1",
    "526772298#3", 
    "-40582826#1", 
    "-40582826#0",
    "-108772672#18",
    "-108772672#17"
]

Comment: There is no other, you do have to go over them and manually add them in the `EDGES_DISTRIBUTION` variable.